# AutoHotKey Script Not Working

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

I have an application where we frequently use F1....F12 KEYS. 
F2 shows dropdown list, Shift+F4 selects a record, F10 commits a record and so on...I wanted to automate the above tasks. Since i am newbie to AutoHotKey, i wrote basic script as below

```
^j::
   send, {f2}   //This will show user dropdown list
   send, {+f4} // Shift+F4 will select a record
   send, {f12} //User visits last page
   send, {+E}  // Ctrl+E expands a record
   send, {f10} //Commit 
 Return
```

First line of code works, however its is stuck at 2nd line,. What am i doing wrong

Comment: `+` should be before `{`, and you might want to insert `sleep 100` after each send. Ctrl-E is `^e`.

Comment: I recommend using a more descriptive question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119878/autohotkey-script-not-working#comment77210568_45119878) is right.

```
SetKeyDelay, 180
^j
send, {f2}
send, +{f4}
send, {f12}
send, ^e
send, {f10}
return
```